# How can I build an activity stream without using too much data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I am developing a social network using ASP.NET 5 and I'd like to develop an activity stream feature.  I currently store actions (PostAdded, PictureAdded) etc in the database, and I'd like to be able to transmit them via HTTP without using a massive amount of data.  If a user didn't follow too many other users, then I wouldn't be too concerned with this, but I'm afraid that if a user were to follow 300 users who were constantly active, then each time they started the app or updated their activity stream, the app might download over 1GB of data.  What are some things I can implement to get around this?

Comment: What data you currently post..?

Comment: If you need more explanation or examples, I may give you some sources to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, what are you thinking about, but let me explain activity stream some.

First of all, users activity stream does not means that every user have to download something. And it also does not means that if user follows to 300 users, then activity stream have to show all data concurrently.

My approach: don't store images or any other media-files in your databases, it is worst solution. You have to store files in your file system and have a link in your database (e.g. Image name, video name, image folder, video folder, so on). And when any user open his activity stream, you will show, for example, just 30 last activities. And you may do autoload next activities (like Facebook's activities), or create some *SEE MORE ACTIVITIES* button (like Facebook's comment block).

**THE MOST IMPORTANT IS TO CONSTRUCT YOUR DATABASE SCHEME CORRECTLY!!!**